# can't login in the login screen

Tags: release-freya, greeter, folder, home

I use elementary freya. 3.16.0-77-generic 14.04.1 ubuntu.  when I installed my laptop, i used the coded home folder. so now I have the following problem;
I can't login in the GUI. My laptop was running perfect with freya. Today I wanted to choose a new password for my account by using the system settings úsers'icon for it. that seemd to work. after i rebooted my machine for another reason, I was stucked! I wanted to do the Xauthority procedure.....but I have no normal home folder. My home folder has no .Xauthority file, only codes in every subfolder I look.  When I choose ctrl- alt- F2, I see the console mode.  And I can login with my new password. So the password is correct...

Can someone help me? only choose a new password to get this trouble. I feel very sorry now i have chosen a coded home partition during installation. I can't solve it if there is a Xauthority problem since that is coded to.

1. console login works with the new password. (text modus)
2. at the welcome screen not.

Help.

Comment: anybody? I'm trying to surf the net for someone with a similar problem. But there is nothing in case of a encoded home folder. Only normal home folders, where people get the advice to chown the .Xauthority file. I can't since I have a encrypted home folder.....I like to do the Xauthority chown trick, but when I log in in the text modus (ctrl+alt+F1) yes, that works. I see only a .private folder with coded files. I have tried to install a property gui radeon driver 2 days ago, but decided to go back to the open source driver. Can this be a reason? Yesterday after rebooting it seemed fine.

Comment: update: i did this to: https://www.computersnyou.com/4947/how-to-solve-ubuntu-login-loop-quick-tip/ Doesn't work. I hate to loose my setup just for this silly situation. How to chown my .Xaurthority in a ENCRYPTED home folder....

Comment: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7112/no-password-change-with-encrypted-home-folder - similar situation

Answer (score 0):

0
down vote

solved:

added new user by using Ctrl+alt+F1 terminal. (#sudo adduser tester), enter all questions. After (Ctrl+Alt+F6) to go back to GUI. login with the new account, it logs in. Go to system settings user and click on the user account settings. click on your own account (original account) en enter the new password. Change after that my own account's password to the old password of this account I used before I had the problem. logged out of the test account.The login sacreen appears. logged in with my own account with old password. Voila!

Dear elementary os developer, can this be a bug? I only chose a different password in the gui to have this problem. It seems after changing the password by using elementary os gui, i changes the unix password in terminal but somthing goes wrong.

This kind of situation is very bad for any user with a encrypted home folder.